# Supremum of measurable function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and for each $t \in [a,b]$ let $Y_t$ be a Banach space. Let $F_t:X \to Y_t$ be a bounded map for each $t$.

I know that for given $u \in X^*$ and for all $w \in X$,
$$\frac{|\langle u, w \rangle_{X^*,X}|}{\lVert F_t w \rVert_{Y_t}}$$
is continuous with respect to $t.$ Is it true that
$$\sup_{w \in X}\frac{|\langle u, w \rangle_{X^*,X}|}{\lVert F_t w \rVert_{Y_t}}$$
is measurable with respect to $t$?

Comment: Is $F_t$ linear?

Comment: Yes, $F_t:X \to Y_t$ is a linear operator (for each $t$).

Comment: Is $X$ separable?

Comment: Yep. I have in mind $W^{k,p}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $F_t$ is linear you have
$$
\sup_{w \in X}\frac{|\langle u, w \rangle_{X^*,X}|}{\lVert F_t w \rVert_{Y_t}}
=\sup_{w \in \operatorname{Sphere}_X}\frac{|\langle u, w \rangle_{X^*,X}|}{\lVert F_t w \rVert_{Y_t}}
$$
Since $X$ is separable we have a countable dense subset $S:=\{w_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \operatorname{Sphere}_X$. Since $S$ is dense in $\operatorname{Ball}_X$, then
$$
\sup_{w \in \operatorname{Sphere}_X}\frac{|\langle u, w \rangle_{X^*,X}|}{\lVert F_t w \rVert_{Y_t}}
=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{|\langle u, w_n \rangle_{X^*,X}|}{\lVert F_t w_n \rVert_{Y_t}}
$$
Hence the desired supremum is measurable as supremum of the *sequence* of measurable functions (note that continuous fnctions are measurable).

Comment: Thanks, what is $\text{Ball}_X$? Never seen that before.

Comment: $\operatorname{Ball}_X=\{x\in X: \Vert x\Vert\leq 1\}$

Comment: Are you sure the supremum is not over $\{ x \in X : \lVert x \rVert =1 \}$ instead? This is what I get when I divide top and bottom of the LHS of the first equation by $\lVert w \rVert$.

Comment: @aere, both approaches are valid. So I'll change the explanation if you wish.

Comment: @Norbert How do you know that you can replace the supremum by one over a denset subset? Is it obvious?

Comment: Take a sequence $(w_n)\subset \operatorname{Sphere}_X$ tending to for which we can attiain the supremum. Approximate each $w_n$ by $s_n\in S$ from with distnace $<1/n$. Since the function under supremum is continuous, then it attains its supremum on thee sequence $(s_n)$

Comment: @Norbert thanks: but you say take sequence $w_n$ tending to an element for which supremum is attained. But $Sph_X$ is not compact so such an element may not exist.

Comment: well, I should say, take $(w_n)$ such that limit of the function in $w_n$ equals to supremum