# Supremum over separable Banach space of a measurable function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. Suppose that $f:[0,T] \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $t \mapsto f(t,x)$ is measurable.

Is the function
$$t \mapsto \sup_{x \in X}f(t,x)$$
also measurable?

I saw this question [Supremum of measurable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477173/supremum-of-measurable-function) but I didn't understand the answer.. why we can replace teh supremum over $X$ by a supremum over a ball of size 1.

Comment: There is this approach in Rudin, when he says that $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty])$ is measurable, and if $g(t) = sup_{x\in X} f(t, x)$, then $g^{-1}((\alpha, \infty]) = \cup_{x\in X} f^{-1}_x((\alpha, \infty])$ where $f_x(t) = f(t, x)$. Do you think that it makes sense? In Rudin, he operates with a countable sequence of measurable functions. I think that you have a non-countable sequence $f_x(t)$ instead, but I also think that it should work in your case.

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't work. I leave the comment for the idea, but since $X$ might be continuum, it doesn't work: a **countable** union of measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: Igor yeah so I think it should be measurable for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

In [Supremum of measurable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477173/supremum-of-measurable-function) there is a specific $f$ with property $f(t, x) = f(t, x/\|x\|)$ for any $x\ne 0$. Thus, you can assume $x$ to be on the $1$-sphere. That isn't valid for any $f$.

Comment: Oh ok. But do you know if a different way works?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean is my function measurable, in the OP?

Comment: @QuestionAnswer: probably not. It might work if $f$ is continuous.